# web scrape with r does not bring the required data

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to bring the data from the eurovision and analyze it
"https://eurovisionworld.com/eurovision/2023", I would like to bring the country, place ,song and artist , and points

I tried the following code: but with no success

```
#install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("robotstxt")
library( robotstxt) 

  
  url2<-"https://eurovisionworld.com/eurovision/2023"
pages2<-read_html(x=url2)
pages2
paths_allowed("https://eurovisionworld.com/eurovision/2023")


country_names <- pages2 %>%
  html_("td:nth-child(1) a") %>%
  html_text()



points <- pages2 %>%
  html_nodes(".chart-table-points") %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those pages where the data is stored as JSON inside a <script>.
The key is to find the script and parse out the data.  In case there is a series of JSON data structures to parse.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

url2<-"https://eurovisionworld.com/eurovision/2023"
pages2<-read_html(x=url2)

#find all the scripts
scripts <- pages2 %>% html_elements("script") 

#find the script with voting data and then split the text at each ;
mydata <- scripts[grep("voting_data", scripts)] %>% html_text() %>%  strsplit(";") %>%  unlist()
# mydata is now a vector of JSON data structures most beginning with 'text =" 

#manually looking at the data it looks like 7 & 8 are the requested data
songs <- gsub(".+ = ", "", mydata[7]) %>% fromJSON() %>% bind_rows() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
names(songs) <- c("Artist", "Song", "other")
songs <- tibble::rownames_to_column(songs, "country")

points <- gsub(".+ = ", "", mydata[8]) %>% fromJSON() %>% bind_rows() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
names(points) <- c("running", "place", "points", "public", "jury", "unknown", "unknown2")
points <- tibble::rownames_to_column(points, "country")

left_join(songs, points)
```

Answer (score 2):

Same logic with somewhat different aproach:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
js <- read_html("https://eurovisionworld.com/eurovision/2023") %>% 
  html_element(xpath = "//head/script[contains(text(),'winner')]") %>% 
  html_text()

# whole block consists only of javascript assignment expressions, 
# if we first split by  ";", well have list of assignments;
# If we split result by "=", we get key-value pairs and latter can be parsed as JSON.
# Keep results as a nested list.
parsed_js <- str_split_1(js, ";") %>% str_split("\\s?=\\s?", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("key", "val")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(str_length(val) > 2) %>% 
  mutate(val = purrr::map(val, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.x))) %>% 
  deframe()

results <- parsed_js$voting_table_main %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_wider(value, names_sep = "_") %>%
  select(1:6) %>% 
  setNames(c("country", "running", "place", "points", "public", "jury"))
print(results, n = 3)
#> # A tibble: 26 × 6
#>   country running place points public  jury
#>   <chr>     <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1 se            9     1    583    243   340
#> 2 fi           13     2    526    376   150
#> 3 il           23     3    362    185   177
#> # ℹ 23 more rows

songs <- parsed_js$voting_songs %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_wider(value, names_sep = "_") %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  setNames(c("country", "artist", "song"))
print(songs, n = 3)
#> # A tibble: 38 × 3
#>   country artist                    song        
#>   <chr>   <chr>                     <chr>       
#> 1 al      Albina & Familja Kelmendi Duje        
#> 2 am      Brunette                  Future Lover
#> 3 au      Voyager                   Promise     
#> # ℹ 35 more rows

left_join(songs,results) %>% arrange(place)
```

Result:

```
#> Joining with `by = join_by(country)`
#> # A tibble: 38 × 8
#>    country artist        song              running place points public  jury
#>    <chr>   <chr>         <chr>               <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
#>  1 se      Loreen        Tattoo                  9     1    583    243   340
#>  2 fi      Käärijä       Cha Cha Cha            13     2    526    376   150
#>  3 il      Noa Kirel     Unicorn                23     3    362    185   177
#>  4 it      Marco Mengoni Due vite               11     4    350    174   176
#>  5 no      Alessandra    Queen of Kings         20     5    268    216    52
#>  6 ua      Tvorchi       Heart of Steel         19     6    243    189    54
#>  7 be      Gustaph       Because of You         16     7    182     55   127
#>  8 ee      Alika         Bridges                12     8    168     22   146
#>  9 au      Voyager       Promise                15     9    151     21   130
#> 10 cz      Vesna         My Sister's Crown      14    10    129     35    94
#> # ℹ 28 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>